# Repeat n times with C++ ranges without dummy variable

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to implement repeat n times using C++20 ranges.
It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/155TvY5hM), but all approaches I can think of need a dummy variable (one for the `for` loop variable, other for arity of lambda).

```
static constexpr int kIterations = 3;

void f1(){
    auto c = '.';
    for (const auto _ :std::views::iota(0)| std::views::take(kIterations) ) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void f2(){
    auto c = '.';
    std::ranges::for_each(std::views::iota(0)| std::views::take(kIterations), [&c](const auto _) {
        std::cout << c;
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with C++20 ranges without the need for dummy variable (`_` in my case, but even unnamed requires const? auto).

notes:

- I know I can use C for loop, I am interested in doing this in C++20 ranges way.
- I guess I can implement this in an algorithm myself, but I wonder if I can do it "inline" without me implementing `repeat_n`
- I know `iota` has version that takes 2 integers, it might be more readable, but still does not fix the problem with dummy variables.
- logic is simplified, just to show capture

Comment: range-v3 has `views::repeat` and `views::repeat_n`.

Comment: In the lambda you can at least omit naming the variable.

Comment: Transforming the iota view also uses a dummy variable `for (const auto e : std::views::iota(0, kIterations) | std::views::transform([&c](int){ return c }) { std::cout << e; }`.

Comment: @super true, my mistake, but it still needs auto/const auto

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, can you clarify what you want to do? Are you trying to implement Range-v3's `repeat_n` in C++20 relying on C++20's `<ranges>`? If so, are `f1` and `f2` doing what you would expect when calling `repeat_n([&c](const auto _) { std::cout << c; })`? I've given an answer, but then deleted it because I think I misunderstood.

Comment: @Enlico I just want to avoid the boilerplate, since I do not need the iteration element, all I want is to print out . some number of times... both f1 and f2 do that, but it is spammy.

Comment: Are you ok with using both C++20 ranges and Range-v3?

Comment: @Enlico yes, but IDK if your solution is shorter than the f1 and f2.

Answer (score 3):

A range is a means of iterating over a set of values. You can manufacture those values on demand rather than accessing them from storage, as `iota` does. But ranges are about iterating over a sequence of values.

So any range-based iteration mechanism is going to involve an object representing, at least, the current position in the range. That's just the nature of the beast.

Yes, you could write your own version of `ranges::for_each` which "iterates" over a range but doesn't actually pass those values to the functor:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range Rng, std::invocable Func>
decltype(auto) iterate_no_element(Rng &&rng, Func func)
{
  return std::ranges::for_each(std::forward<Rng>(rng), [func](auto const&){func();})
}
```

But the standard has no such function.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use both C++20 `<ranges>` and `repeat_n` from Range-v3, then this could be an approach?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/repeat_n.hpp>
#include <ranges>

using ranges::views::repeat_n;
using namespace std::ranges::views;
using namespace std::ranges;

auto constexpr invoke = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::invoke); // what a pity we need this

static constexpr int kIterations = 3;

void f() {
    char c = '.';
    for_each(repeat_n([c]{ std::cout << c << std::endl; },
                      kIterations),
             invoke);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

The lambda `[c]{ std::cout << c << std::endl; }` is nullary as it isn't passed any value, and there's no `for` loop with a dummy variable.